# Let $M$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $E$. Prove that for each $x \in E\setminus M$, there exists $m_0 \in E$ such that $d(x,M) = \| x-m_0\|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $M$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $E$. Prove that for each $x \in E\setminus M$, there exists $m_0 \in E$ such that $d(x,M) = \| x-m_0\|$.

I've been stuck in these exercise for some time. I've tried Riesz Lema, hoever I could not get anywhere.

Help?

Comment: Presumably you mean $m_0 \in M$???

Comment: So, $M\setminus E$ isn't a vector space? There is no zero-vector in $M\setminus E$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(m) = \|x-m\|$ is continuous 
and $f(m) \ge \|m\| - \|x\|$, so if $\|m\| \ge 2 \|x\|$ then $f(m) \ge f(0) = \|x\|$. In particular, $D=\overline{B}(0,2\|x\|)$ is compact, so $f$ has a minimiser $m_0$ on $D$, that is,
$f(m_0) \le f(m)$ for all $m$.

Comment: Just to add, the closed ball is compact because $M$ is finite dimensional.